# web application display the last user name logged in

Tags: spring-security

When any user visit log in page he found user name of last logged in user: *displayed in the user name field.
*scope of the log in bean is view scope.

we use spring security 3.2.5 and server  tomcat 7.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: how to prevent this behavior any user access log in page will found user name of last logged in user